# Using a QStyledItemDelegate on a QListView with QSqlQueryModel

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian

I have a QListView, that has a QSqlQueryModel set as its model. How can I use a QStyledItemDelegate in order to customise the QListView's rows' appearence (e.g. show 2 text lines) ?

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QSQLITE" );
db.setDatabaseName( "test.db" );
if( !db.open() )
{
    qDebug() << db.lastError();
    qFatal( "Failed to connect." );
}

qDebug( "Connected!" );

QSqlQueryModel *sqlModel = new QSqlQueryModel;
sqlModel->setQuery("SELECT * FROM entries");

mListWidget->setModel(sqlModel);
```

Essentially, what I think I need to do is to somehow "match" roles to db table's fields, in order to be able to get the data from the QStyledItemDelegate, using something like this:

```
void ListViewDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    [...]
    QString headerText = qvariant_cast<QString>(index.data(headerRole));
    QString subText = qvariant_cast<QString>(index.data(subHeaderRole));
    [...]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You certainly can use QStyledItemDelegate for custom item drawing. QModelIndex has a reference to the model object which you can use to get "entries" record fields. You also have to redefine model's [sizeHint](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstyleditemdelegate.html#sizeHint) method to increase items size if you need to show more data then a single data. Other then that it's more or less trivial.

Pls, see if an example below would work you:

```
class ListViewDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
protected:
    void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
    {
        QStyleOptionViewItemV4 opt = option;
        initStyleOption(&opt, index);

        QString line0 = index.model()->data(index.model()->index(index.row(), 1)).toString();
        QString line1 = index.model()->data(index.model()->index(index.row(), 2)).toString();

        // draw correct background
        opt.text = "";
        QStyle *style = opt.widget ? opt.widget->style() : QApplication::style();
        style->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter, opt.widget);

        QRect rect = opt.rect;
        QPalette::ColorGroup cg = opt.state & QStyle::State_Enabled ? QPalette::Normal : QPalette::Disabled;
        if (cg == QPalette::Normal && !(opt.state & QStyle::State_Active))
            cg = QPalette::Inactive;

        // set pen color
        if (opt.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
            painter->setPen(opt.palette.color(cg, QPalette::HighlightedText));
        else
            painter->setPen(opt.palette.color(cg, QPalette::Text));

        // draw 2 lines of text
        painter->drawText(QRect(rect.left(), rect.top(), rect.width(), rect.height()/2),
                          opt.displayAlignment, line0);
        painter->drawText(QRect(rect.left(), rect.top()+rect.height()/2, rect.width(), rect.height()/2),
                          opt.displayAlignment, line1);
    }

    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const
    {
        QSize result = QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint(option, index);
        result.setHeight(result.height()*2);
        return result;
    }
};
```

The test database set is defined here:

```
QSqlError initDb()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");

    if (!db.open())
        return db.lastError();

    QStringList tables = db.tables();
    if (tables.contains("test", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
        return QSqlError();

    QSqlQuery q;
    if (!q.exec(QLatin1String("create table entries(id integer primary key, first_line varchar, second_line varchar)")))
        return q.lastError();

    q.exec("insert into entries(id, first_line, second_line) values(0, 'first line 0', 'second line 0')");
    q.exec("insert into entries(id, first_line, second_line) values(1, 'first line 1', 'second line 1')");
    q.exec("insert into entries(id, first_line, second_line) values(2, 'first line 2', 'second line 2')");

    return QSqlError();
}
```

model and listview definition:

```
initDb();

QSqlQueryModel *sqlModel = new QSqlQueryModel();
sqlModel->setQuery("SELECT * FROM entries");

ui->listView->setModel(sqlModel);
ui->listView->setItemDelegate(new ListViewDelegate());
```

hope this helps, regards